# cudaMemcpy2DFromArray resulting in cudaErrorInvalidValue

Tags: c++, opengl, cuda

I am having some troubles using OpenGL-CUDA-Interopt
My setup is the following:

I am using a FrameBufferObject for render to texture (this works very well) which I am creating this way:

```
void createFrameBuffer(){

    // Create the texture for the FBO
    glGenTextures(1, &tex_data);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_data);
    SDK_CHECK_ERROR_GL();
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA16F , window_w, window_h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);

    // Create the frameBuffer
    glGenFramebuffersEXT(1, &fbo);
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, fbo);
    // Register the texture with cuda
    checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage(&res_data, tex_data, GL_TEXTURE_2D, cudaGraphicsMapFlagsReadOnly));
    SDK_CHECK_ERROR_GL();
    // attach images

    glGenRenderbuffersEXT(1, &depth_rb);
    glBindRenderbufferEXT(GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, depth_rb);
    glRenderbufferStorageEXT(GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, window_w, window_h);
    //-------------------------


    glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_data, 0);
       //Attach depth buffer to FBO
    glFramebufferRenderbufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_EXT, GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, depth_rb);
    //glFramebufferRenderbufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, color);
    //glFramebufferRenderbufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_EXT, GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, depth);

    // clean up
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);
    SDK_CHECK_ERROR_GL();
}
```

Currently I am not having a kernel, but I want to convert the texture from OpenGL to something that I can use with CUDA. Here is what I am trying for conversion:

```
void processImage(){
    cudaArray *cuda_data = 0;
    checkCudaErrors( cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage(&res_data, tex_data, GL_TEXTURE_2D, cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsReadOnly));
    float *dData; // Array holding the data
    std::cout << "cudaMalloc " << std::endl;
    checkCudaErrors( cudaMalloc(&dData, window_w * window_h*4*sizeof(float)));   

    std::cout << "Mapping Resource" << std::endl;
    checkCudaErrors( cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &res_data) );

    std::cout << "cudaGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray" << std::endl;
    checkCudaErrors( cudaGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray(&cuda_data, res_data, 0, 0));

    std::cout << "cudaMemcpy2DFromArray" <<  std::endl;
    // Copy from the texture to the graphic Card
    checkCudaErrors( cudaMemcpy2DFromArray(dData, window_w*4*sizeof(float), cuda_data ,0 ,0, window_w*4*sizeof(float), window_h, cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice));

    std::cout << "cudaGraphicsUnmapResources" << std::endl;
    // Unmap the resource
    checkCudaErrors( cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &res_data));
}
```

The problem is when executing the program CUDA throws an error:

> CUDA error at
>   e:\workspace\master\gradientrenderer\gradientrenderer\source.cpp:175
>   code=11(cudaErrorInvalidValue) "cudaMemcpy2DFromArray(dData,
>   window_w*4*sizeof(float), cuda_data ,0 ,0, window_w*4*sizeof(float),
>   window_h, cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice)"

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? As this is part of a bigger project using a predefined kernel (no way to change this kernel) I need to call **cudaMemcpy2DFromArray** so that the texture is correctly transferred to the kernel.

Comment: You haven't provided a repro case someone else could compile and run, but I would guess the problem is that the pitch of cuda memory allocation you provided to the `cudaMemcpy2DFromArray` is invalid. You should allocate memory using `cudaMalloc2D` to get a memory pitch.

Comment: `cudaMalloc2D` ==> `cudaMallocPitch`